# Making my TCP server Internet-facing - where should I start?

Tags: mfc, tcp, client-server

I have written a client/server code.
The server program executes on a terminal which plainly receives text data from the client and the client is a GUI where in you could specify the IP address of the machine where the server would be running.

However this works only in a closed Network(LAN).
I have just learnt TCP IP and have written a few codes that run on a LAN.
I wanted to make this program work across the network(over the internet). 
But I have some basic doubts like,does one need the permission of the local ISP for such programs to execute across the internet.Does it involve buying a domain or some kind of permissions?
Can some one please help me on,what should I be doing,or where should I start from?

Comment: Have you tried it if it's working across the Internet? If it doesn't, why? I don't think you need any permission at all. All browsers, FTP clients, servers, etc work across the Internet. Why do you think you need permission?

Comment: Should I paste the source cod to be more clear? I have tried it but it does not connect.And there is a good possibility that its only because I may have done something wrong.But it works fine in a closed network.I thought may be because we are talking to another machine directly my program could be blocked by some internal firewalls.Pardon me all what I'm saying may be wrong.I'm a novice

Comment: No, it's very clear. Internal firewall is not blocking you as you can connect in LAN. So, you only have to set port forwarding on your router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listener have to have IP port opened in some way. If you are behind router, you should set proper port forwarding on router and if ISP provides its own subnet, you should know how to setup such link. (i do not know what kind of tehnology ISP might use for this).

For beginning you do not need you own domain name but you should be able to address by ip. If you need domain, register own domain name or create subdomain for free (i was using http://freedns.afraid.org/ )

Answer (score 0):

If your server is behind a router which creates a LAN, you have to configure the router that it will forward the packages from your client to the server.
You have to forward all the incoming packages at the specific port to the local ip of the server.

Comment: How do I do this? Can this be achieved programmatically? I'm not that good at configuring routers.

Comment: The process is similar but really depends on your router model. Usually there's a "Config" or "Settings" page (from the web interface that most routers have) where you can configure "Port forwarding" to your server program. The clients will then have to connect to your public IP (your router's external IP) or you can use some dynamic service (like: http://no-ip.com/ )